# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error...?

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration

I get this error in the apache error log:

`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

My `.htaccess` file looks like:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule    ^view/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    view.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^report/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  report.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^verifyAccount/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ verifyAccount.php?hash=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.nitrobit.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.nitrobit.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I googled the problem and I saw that the solution for some people is to add this line in the htaccess file: `RewriteBase /`. I did it and the error stays.

What is the solution? Thanks you very much, and sorry for my English

Comment: Find out what rule is being matched over and over again (comment them out one by one until the error goes away). I've had troubles with the one-but-last rule in the past in specific cases (I believe when a directory exists with a certain name and not a file, the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` would return true. I would add an extra condition that the URI may not end with `.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Reordering your rules and putting an additional condition:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.nitrobit\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.nitrobit.net/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^view/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ view.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^report/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ report.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^verifyAccount/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ verifyAccount.php?hash=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

# if it has not been rewritten then find a .php handler
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Still having this problem

Comment: Now I have this error - `File does not exist: /home/nitrobit/domains/nitrobit.net/public_html/view, referer:http://www.nitrobit.net/view/4LrsSAyev`